# Error in saving/opening file after deploying .net C# MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

In my MVC application I am exporting data to excel using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` .

I have also enabled `ASP.NET Impersonation` and gave the authentication details. It writes data to excel but it doesn't save or opens the excel file. It throws a exception `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`. I will be so glad if anyone could help. thanks in advance.

My code for Export is:

```
public static void ExportExcel(this DataTable Tbl, string ExcelFilePath = null)
        {
            ExcelFilePath = "ExportTable.xls";
            try
            {
                if (Tbl == null || Tbl.Columns.Count == 0)
                    //throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

                // load excel, and create a new workbook
                Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

                // single worksheet
                Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                // column headings
                for (int i = 0; i < Tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = Tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)].Font.Bold = true;
                    workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)].Font.Size = 12;
                }

                // rows
                for (int i = 0; i < Tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // to do: format datetime values before printing
                    for (int j = 0; j < Tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = Tbl.Rows[i][j];
                    }
                }
                // works fine till here
                // check fielpath
                if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        workSheet.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);
                        excelApp.Quit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"+ ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else    // no filepath is given
                {
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message); 
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS user account has to have permissions to write the file.

Search for 0x800A03EC in the following article, [How to Create Excel file in ASP.NET C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jayendra/how-to-create-excel-file-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

HRESULT: 0x800A03EC is an unknown (to VB.Net) COM error. This usually happens when Excel throws some error because your input or parameters were wrong. If you try your code in Excel VBA it is often easier to figure out the problem.